# Controller delivers html as string to jquery to open content in new window

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following html button which has the onclick even handler `OpenHTML`:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="OpenHTML('@element.MSNAME')">
   Open HTML
</button>
```

The functions calls a Controller (Get-Method) which delivers a string of html.

Javscript Code:

```
<script>
function OpenHTML(mappingID) {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $.get("/Home/OpenHTMLnew?appID=" + mappingID, function (data) { });

    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}
</script>
```

C#-Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult OpenHTMLnew(string appID)
{
   string html = "<p>test</p>";

   return Content(html, "text/html");
}
```

So far. If I click on the button jQuery opens a new Window as I wished to do. But there is no Content inside the new Window. Can someone help me to deliver `string html = "..."` to new window which jQuery opens.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your action getting called in controller?

Comment: yes I check this Point with breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to like this:

```
<script>
function OpenHTML(mappingID) {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $.get("/Home/OpenHTMLnew?appID=" + mappingID, function (data) { 
$(w.document.body).html(data);
});


}
</script>
```

http://prntscr.com/d2zpze
As you can see in image, when you console.log html in function it is returning function not the content.

Comment: The Second fix solved my problem. Thanks for the explanation of the error.